# Spring boot not detecting that controller is not there

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mapping

I've been learning Spring Boot and I've ran into a problem. I have made a few projects so far but the current one I'm working on is the biggest one so far so there are more mappings here than there were in the ones before.

I wanted to move one of these mappings to a different package but after moving it said something along the lines of there being another mapping named like that so I changed the url of the mapping to see if it maybe fixed the problem. It did, and I could reach the new mapping at the new url but it introduced another problem: an autowired variable (lateinit var) not being autowired but rather just throwing exception that a lateinit var has not been initialized. So I look into the console of Spring Boot and here is the output from there:

```
2018-08-18 14:25:11.169  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/app/playlist/{playlistId}],methods=[GET]}" onto private java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.AppController.showPlaylist(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,int)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.170  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/app/playlists],methods=[GET]}" onto private java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.AppController.showPlaylists(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.170  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/app/albums],methods=[GET]}" onto private java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.AppController.showAlbums(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.171  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login/loginErrorSpotify]}" onto public java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.LoginController.loginError()
2018-08-18 14:25:11.171  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login/spotify],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.LoginController.loginToSpotify(org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,java.lang.String)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.172  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/login/afterLoginSpotify],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.LoginController.afterLogin(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.174  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/progress/{downloadId}],methods=[GET]}" onto private java.lang.Object hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.rest.DownloadController.downloadProgress(java.lang.String)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.174  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/file/{downloadId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/zip]}" onto private void hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.rest.DownloadController.getDownloadZip(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.175  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[POST],produces=[text/plain]}" onto public java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.rest.DownloadController.downloadUris(java.util.List<java.lang.String>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.175  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/load/isAvailable/{attrName}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.rest.MiscRestController.isAttributeAvailableInSession(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.176  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/download/progress/{downloadId}],methods=[GET]}" onto private java.lang.Object hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.RESTController.downloadProgress(java.lang.String)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.176  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/download/file/{downloadId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/zip]}" onto private void hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.RESTController.getDownloadZip(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.177  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/download],methods=[POST],produces=[text/plain]}" onto public java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.RESTController.downloadUris(java.util.List<java.lang.String>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.177  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/isAvailable/{attrName}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String hu.zsemberi.spotifytoyoutube.controller.RESTController.isAttributeAvailableInSession(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.180  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.180  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.203  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Mapped URL path [/download] onto handler '/download'
2018-08-18 14:25:11.210  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-18 14:25:11.210  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-18 14:25:11.231  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in repositoryRestExceptionHandler
2018-08-18 14:25:11.658  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter   : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@8665cb9: startup date [Sat Aug 18 14:25:04 CEST     2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-18 14:25:11.673  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-08-18 14:25:11.674  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-08-18 14:25:11.674  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-08-18 14:25:11.674  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-08-18 14:25:11.674  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-08-18 14:25:11.675  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-08-18 14:25:11.677  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.optionsForRepositories()
2018-08-18 14:25:11.678  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.headForRepositories()
2018-08-18 14:25:11.678  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
2018-08-18 14:25:11.681  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.681  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.682  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.682  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.682  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.682  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.682  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchesResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.683  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
2018-08-18 14:25:11.686  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.686  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-08-18 14:25:11.686  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.687  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-08-18 14:25:11.687  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-08-18 14:25:11.687  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-08-18 14:25:11.687  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-08-18 14:25:11.688  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-08-18 14:25:11.688  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-08-18 14:25:11.688  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-08-18 14:25:11.692  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-08-18 14:25:11.692  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
2018-08-18 14:25:11.693  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
2018-08-18 14:25:11.693  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
2018-08-18 14:25:11.693  INFO 20992 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
```

And here are the controllers I'm using (these are in separate files):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = ["/login"])
class LoginController {
    @GetMapping("/spotify")
    fun loginToSpotify() {..}

    @GetMapping("/afterLoginSpotify")
    fun afterLogin() {..}

    @RequestMapping("/loginErrorSpotify")
    fun loginError() {..}
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = ["/app"])
class AppController {
     @GetMapping("/playlists")
     fun showPlaylists() {..}

     @GetMapping("/albums")
     fun showAlbums() {..}

     @GetMapping("/playlist/{playlistId}")
     fun showPlaylist() {..}
}

@RestController(value = "/download")
class DownloadController {
    @PostMapping("/", produces = ["text/plain"])
    fun downloadUris() {..}

    @GetMapping("/progress/{downloadId}")
    fun downloadProgress() {..}

    @GetMapping("/file/{downloadId}", produces = ["application/zip"])
    fun getDownloadZip() {..}
}
```

As you can see I don't have that many controllers as spring think I do. After writing these out the original problem (varaible not initalizing) has been solved by god knows what but it still writes these mappings out. What could be the problem?

My pom file just in case it is needed: https://pastebin.com/266Fbi8E

Answer (score 1):

It resolved itself. I'm not sure how though because I didn't do anything, I just ran the project a couple of times after coming back to it a few hours later.